# Are elliptical rings feasible?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, orbital-mechanics, planetary-rings

Around a rocky planet or small gas giant, could there be a system of rings that follow an elliptical orbit? I have used a gravity simulator ([this one](https://testtubegames.com/gravity.html)) to test it, but the way it handles its particles doesn't seem like it would work. My question is, can a planet have an elliptical ring system?

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/can-there-be-elliptical-rings-around-a-planet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unlikely, on the whole, for a ring system to maintain a high eccentricity on significant timescales. Dissipative collisions tend to circularize the orbits of individual particles, even if the original constituent body traveled on a fairly eccentric orbit. Therefore, you need some external perturbation keeping the particles on substantially elliptical orbits.

This typically involves another orbiting body - say, a moon - creating, for instance, a [Lindblad resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindblad_resonance) with a subset of the particles in the ring that have the proper orbital period. These particles will be forced into slightly more eccentric orbits. While this has not occurred stably on a large scale in the present-day Solar System, it *might* occur in some circumstellar disks around other stars. The star Fomalhaut has a ring of dust of eccentricity $e\simeq0.11\pm0.01$ orbiting at a distance of $a\simeq133\text{ AU}$. The star is a couple hundred million years old, but the circularization timescale is only $\tau\sim10^6$ years. It has been suggested that the culprit is a planet orbiting at $a_p\simeq119\text{ AU}$, with an eccentricity similar to that of the disk ([Quillen 2006](https://academic.oup.com/mnrasl/article/372/1/L14/1386596)). The theory holds up, but observations have not confirmed such an object.

In short, yes, it's quite possible for there to be a ring system that maintains a fairly eccentric shape for long periods of time, but there needs to be a perturbing body (a high-mass moon, for instance) in the proper orbit to force the ring particles to maintain their eccentricities. Otherwise, collisions will very quickly circularize the ring system.